# Create matrix from image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am strugling with a simple task:

Create a matrix $A$ when you know that the image of $A$ has the basis $\langle \{ 1, 4 ,1 \}; \{ 3, 6, 2\} \rangle$ and $A(T)$ (transpose) has the image with basis $\langle \{ 1, 1, 1 \} ; \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \rangle$.

As I know the image of a matrix is defined as all linear combinations of it's columns. And if you remove all the linear related vectors in the image you get the basis.
Also I figured that the Matrix $A$ has to be a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Also was not sure how correct formatting of vectors works in this subsite

Comment: < { 1, 2, 3 } ; { 1, 2, 3 } > can't be a basis since it is not linearly independent.

Comment: @RandyE sry that was a typo. Should be 1,1,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The matrix could be a linear combination of $\displaystyle \pmatrix{1\cr 4\cr 1\cr} \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1}$ and ...